# How to move a VideoView in a diagonal way from bottom left to top right of the screen

Tags: android, android-animation, android-videoview

I want to move a videoview without touching (*No dragging,No user involvement) while it's playing , the movement should be from the top right corner to the bottom left of the screen in a diagonal path. I tried different animations but I unable to achieve this, Tried the following code.

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview2);

animateVideoView(mVideoView);

private void animateVideoView(View v){

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    final int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    final int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

ObjectAnimator y = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v,
                "translationY", width, 100);

        ObjectAnimator x = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v,
                "translationX",100,height);

        animSetXY.playTogether(x, y);
        animSetXY.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animSetXY.setDuration(5000);
        animSetXY.start();
        v.startAnimation(animSetXY);



}
```

any help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this library, it might help https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel